# Wordpress WPML, Custom post type multiple languages - that aren't switched on

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

Have a multilingual Wordpress website using WPML, it is currently running in 5 specific languages ( English, English US, Spanish, German, French).

We have a custom post type that we need to be able to convert into several more languages.  The premise being that we will have a drop down on the post saying "View this post in : Brazilian, " etc.

Googling & Searching has found no solution, we really want to be able to keep the header / footer in English (or the current WPML language) and just switch the custom post types content .

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if anything needs clarifying please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that is not Brazilian, it's Portuguese.